# Use subprocess in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, audio-recording, popen

I am writing a small program in Python, to record an audio WITH printing some text at same time.

But my Print is executed until finishing of audio recording.
Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

```
import picamera, subprocess, os, sys

a1 = "arecord -f cd -D plughw:0 -d 10 a.wav"
subprocess.call(a1,shell= True)
print("Audio record is only for 10sec")
```

Comment: Well, you could put `print` right below the `subprocess.call()` - it won't wait for the `arecord` to end then :) Otherwise, you can use [threads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) to run it simultaneously.

Comment: @IgorHatarist but in actual practice, It is waiting for audio end then print the text.. i m exactly doing same what you said

Comment: Hm, I can't reproduce it. Are you sure that if you swap lines containing `subprocess.call` and `print`, the message still won't show up after the record is finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), which blocks:

> Run the command described by args. **Wait for command to complete**, then return the returncode attribute.

You can use a [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) object, which doesn't block:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(a1.split())
# code will proceed

# use proc.communicate later on
```

Or you can have two things run separately using a [`Thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects) (which then spawns a process in it's own context):

```
import picamera, subprocess, os, sys
import threading

def my_process():
    a1 = "arecord -f cd -D plughw:0 -d 10 a.wav"
    subprocess.call(a1,shell= True)
thread = threading.Thread(target=my_process)
thread.start()
print("Audio record is only for 10sec")
```

Comment: when I use `proc = subprocess.Popen(a1.spilt())` instead of `subprocess.call(a1,shell= True)` it is showing me an error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'spilt'`

Comment: threads are unnecessary here. You should not call `.communicate()` unless any of the pipes is redirected, use `.wait()` instead.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Can you please edit my coding, to make `subprocess.Popen` error free

Comment: `spilt` is an obvious typo. Use `a1.split()` as shown in the answer instead.